# How to properly invoke motd for SSH connections with PAM disabled

Tags: ssh, login, pam, motd

I have configured a nice motd message that shows me lots of relevant infos when I login to my VPS via SSH.

As password authentication is disabled in `sshd_config` I would also prefer to disable PAM as it's just not needed.

Motd is however invoked by PAM and if PAM is disabled so is the motd message. **How can be achieved that motd is displayed for SSH logins with PAM disabled in a proper and clean way?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: Would like to have an answer for this as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on your server and un-comment or add the following line:

```
PrintMotd yes
```

Then restart SSH with `sudo service ssh restart`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already it doesn't work. Maybe it only works with PAM?

Answer (score 0):

Pam must be enabled to display MOTD.

See posts #17-20 on the following link.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/543767